# Mesh only shows in wireframe in Edit mode

Tags: mesh, wireframe

[image][image][image]My mesh only shows up as wireframe in Edit mode, no matter which mode I am in. If I am in solid view it just hides my mirror and stays wireframe. I've looked at other posts where the maximum draw type is set to wireframe, yet mine is set to textured so I really don't know why this is. As you can see, I've added three images of my mesh in three different views.

Comment: that's a weird issue.

Comment: Any idea of what it might be?

Comment: Posting screenshots/gifs/videos of the issue will be great to help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have *Hidden Wire* activated in the *Shading* panel.

[image: Hidden wire actived]
[image: Hidden wire deactivated]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my problem! I really have no idea how I might've toggled that.